# Is there a way to prevent overwriting existing tags/images in Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-registry, azure-container-registry

I got a pipeline in Azure Devops which has a task that pushes a Docker image to an Azure Container Registry. I want to know if there's a way to prevent this task to overwrite any existing Docker tags/images.

Comment: Can you give an example scenario of the problem? At a high level, the Push Image task is just calling docker push https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/ so the typical pattern is to tag your images with some kind of versioning (numbers, alpha/beta, etc.)

Comment: @KyleHale example I already have a tag named 1.0.0 in my ACR. If I run the pipeline from Azure Devops and it tries to push an image with a tag of 1.0.0 to my ACR, the pipeline execution should fail

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-image-lock)

> By default, a tagged image in Azure Container Registry is mutable, so with appropriate permissions you can repeatedly update and push an image with the same tag to a registry. Container images can also be deleted as needed. This behavior is useful when you develop images and need to maintain a size for your registry.

> However, when you deploy a container image to production, you might need an immutable container image. An immutable image is one that you can't accidentally delete or overwrite.

Using the Azure CLI, to lock a single image by tag:

```
az acr repository update \
--name myregistry --image myrepo/myimage:tag \
--write-enabled false
```

You can also lock the entire repository:

```
az acr repository update \
--name myregistry --repository myrepo/myimage \
--write-enabled false
```

There's also a `--delete-enabled` argument to prevent images or repos from being deleted (though they can still be overwritten.)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.

Comment: you can use this command in YML file right after building your image and It will lock your image and next time if you run the same command it will fail...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on yml you can refere to this.
I implemented for github actions.

```
- name: Check if image exists
    id: check_image
    run: |
      set -e
      if docker pull "${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}"; then
        echo "::set-output name=image_exists::true"
      else
        echo "::set-output name=image_exists::false"
      fi

  - name: Build the Docker image
    if: steps.check_image.outputs.image_exists != 'true'
    run: docker build --tag "${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}" --file ./docker/Dockerfile ./src 

  - name: Push the Docker image
    if: steps.check_image.outputs.image_exists != 'true'
    run: docker push "${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}"
```